# JQuery Grid or Loop through partial views?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, partial-views

Has anyone been able to customize jQGrid?

While I'd like something easy I can pluing and use that provides paging, I find that the layout is "tight" ( not in the cool way ) the gird is too excel-like.

I'd much prefer one with spaced out grid rows and ability to use icons.

But before I write the grid off and start hand rolling a lot of code, I thought I'd ask the community if anyone has been able to customize JQGrid successfully (the grid layout and Column types )

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I've found a possible answer here:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=18/feature-request/icons-with-data/page-1&value=icons%25251&search=1

Hi.
Credit for this answer goes to Tony for he mentioned it in an earlier thread.
For waht you want you could possibly use tree grid for folder structure and for the pictures and all else needed, just pass the html source through the server response.
For example.

```
colNames: ['Item','Image','Price'], 
colModel: [ name:"item",index:"item"....}, 
      ... ],
```

then server response could be:

```
rows : [
[id:"1", cell:["item", "html img tag",...]],
…
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers,
P.

I'll give this a whirl first before doing partial views, would appreciate any input form others who've used this approach though!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not done it, but the alpha version of jqGrid supports the jQuery themeroller  - potentially that offers better customization than the stable version.